# Recursively move all files in folders with given name to their parent directory

Tags: bash, file, directory, move

I have a document library where all of my files are in  folder based on category name but then they are also all in subfolders called 'pdf' as well. Is there a way in bash to scan through all of the directories in the library and move all files in folders named pdf to their parent directory?

Comment: This belongs on SuperUser, IMO. it's really an OS/shell question, not a programming question.

Comment: In the future please do not cross-post. Your question could have been moved. @NikMartin, it'd be helpful if you explained to users how questions can automatically be migrated instead of encouraging to just post their question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a *find* command.

Assuming you have no other folders named **pdf**, you could run something like this:

```
cd path_to_library
find . -type d -name pdf -exec bash -c 'cd {}; mv * ..' ';'
```